# teajs Vs. node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just found out about [teajs](http://code.google.com/p/teajs/). Now I wonder, what are the main pros/cons when compared with [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). I know, teajs is a FastCGI based webserver and node.js is a standalone JavaScript engine that can run server applications. But other than that, what are noticeable differences? (I couldn't find a good comparison article with Google.)

Comment: Better call it TeaJs now, according to doc :)

Comment: teajs is a set of libraries. nodejs is a runtime environment.